# Data grid is not updating after setting item source to null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid that is bound to an observable collection, when I update the items in the observable collection the data grid is not updating. I know that I notify won't fire since i'm not changing the collection just the properties, so I am trying to set the item source to null and the rebinding it after it checks for updates, but this is not working. Also I have tried items.refresh to no avail. The only thing I have found that works is by renavigating back to the PendingChanges page.

To get an idea of how this works. I have a window that has a page in it, and at the bottom is a window that is framed in, when you click a button it navigates to the window that contains the datagrid (pending changes)

**Class and Page that contains the datagrid**

```
public PendingChanges(page blahh)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Datagrid.ItemsSource = obvs_collection;
}
public string GetPendingChanges()
{
    PopulatePendingChanges();
    return NumberOfItemsPending + " items checked out";
}
private void PopulateCollection()
{
    //obvs_collection.Clear();  this doesn't work
    //Datagrid.ItemsSource = null this doesn't work 
    foreach (var path in localPath)
    {
        obvs_collection.Add(new PendingItem()
        {
            ID = blah.Replace("\\",""),
            Path = path.ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

**Class/Page that frames in the page with the data grid**

```
private void CheckChanges()
{
    _pendingChangesPage = new PendingChanges(blah);
    PendingChangesTb.Text = _pendingChangesPage.GetPendingChanges();
}
```

Comment: after nulling it out have you tried calling Datagrid.Items.Refresh();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you would probably want just a single instance instead of creating a new one everytime you check for changes.

Try this:

```
PendingChanges _pendingChangesPage;

public PendingChanges(page blahh)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Datagrid.ItemsSource = obvs_collection;
   _pendingChangesPage = new PendingChanges(blah);
}

private void CheckChanges()
{
    PendingChangesTb.Text = _pendingChangesPage.GetPendingChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the grid using its .Refersh() function when you update any data source to reflect its changes.

```
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```